# Obj-c: Segue crash..navigation controller in the middle

Tags: ios, objective-c

I do not understand why this segue crash.[image]

In the first class, i have:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
}
}
```

> But

If I remove the navigation controller in the middle, the segue works perfectly. Why?

Comment: What is the crash saying?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina `[UINavigationController setUrl:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdba6028c00
2017-07-18 16:22:52.285 RSSReader[49671:2755029] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setUrl:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdba6028c00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because, **setUrl** is defined in Last View Controller. Remember it's **viewcontroller instance**. Where as when navigation controller is there in middle, the `[segue destinationViewController]` gives **NavigationController Instance** where setURL variable won't available.

If you want NavigationController to be there you have to caste it. Simply Do this.

```
UINavigationController *navControl = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
let vc = navControl.rootViewController;
vc.setUrl = string;
```

Comment: How fix...? x.x

Comment: Updated the answer check

Comment: Work bu the button back in the viewController() disappears and the animation is strange (it appears from the bottom and goes up) :O

Comment: Yes, it happens because you are pushing it from firstViewcontroller for which NavigationController is not there. So It presents the view controller

Comment: If you want push animation and back button, you need to add that navigatoin View controller in front of MainTableview controller.

Comment: Concept is simple: The back button only comes with pushing view controller. If you want to push view controller you need navigation controller. The origin view controller that is from where you are pushing, the destination viewcontroller, to where you are pushing should be in stack of navigation controller. To put those two in stack, you have to add Navigation controller before these two controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UINavigationController *navigation = [segue destinationViewController];
YourViewController * controller = navigation.rootViewController
[controller setUrl:string];
```

Comment: Work bu  the button back in the viewController() disappears and the animation is strange (it appears from the bottom and goes up) :O

Comment: In Storyboard select first segue (from Master Table View Controller to UINavigationController) and change Kind to : Show (e.g. Push)